# how to know where a fab button is used in project (activity and fragment and xml)?

Tags: android, android-studio, search, floating-action-button

I need to change color of all fabs in my project . I set color for each individually and can't change them from one place 
the problem is I don't know where I used fab in project . I have to search all project and it is so Time-consuming.

how can I find them easily to modify faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android Studio click Edit -> Find -> "Find In Path", input FloatingActionButton and optionally click "Open in Find Window"

Comment: it is correct , thx 
another solotion may be double tab on shift shearch for the name fab , (although it shows fab name variable )